# not enough primary partitions available

Tags: dual-boot

I own an MSi laptop.
There are 4 partitions: 2 recovery (hidden) and 2 dynamic. Win7 is on a dynamic disk.
I want to install Ubuntu 11 on my laptop as well.
I can't make another primary partition.
When i would be able to make another primary partition (ie the 3rd) im still stuck with the recovery disks. This means there is only 1 primary partition available for the os.

How to get the 2 dynamic disk into a primary one.
How to release 1 of the 2 hidden partitions without losing the recover data?

Comment: You kept using the word disk when you meant partition.  Corrected.

Comment: You only need one primary partition to install Ubuntu so long as that primary partition is set as an extended partition. Then you can have more partitions inside the extended one. I have 2 primary partitions, 1 extended partition (it is technically a primary partition) and four logical partitions inside the extended partition.

Comment: I have been doing further research. Be very careful because your Windows disks/partitions are dynamic and I have read that Linux is not compatible with dynamic disk types. See this [link](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=dynamic+disk+partitions)

Comment: I have found this Microsoft [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309044). It seems that you have to convert the dynamic disk to a basic disk but this destroys all the data in them. so, you will have to backup and then re-install Windows (possibly).

Comment: Thnx, i've read that article too.I wonder when i could plug in the laptops hd into my 2nd pc if i could make the dynamic part. primary again?
I would like to copy the 2 hidden part. But since they are inaccessible i really don't know how to do so.
Mind my laptop is only 3 months old. All the problems started when i wanted to install Ubunty )-*

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand your question very well but here is a possible answer.

Since you have four primary partitions you can't create another because a disk (with an msdos-style [partition table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table), as is common) can have at [most four primary partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types):

> The total data storage space of a PC hard disk can be divided into at
>   most four primary partitions, or alternatively three primary
>   partitions and an extended partition. These partitions are described
>   by 16-byte entries that constitute the Partition Table, located in the
>   master boot record.

So, you must delete one partition and crate an extended one. Then you can create as many partitions as you want within this extended one. Doing this is up to you. Maybe you can move your data to another available partition or USB disk. After this you can shape your disk for your needs.

Comment: NO, 2 hidden part. ( and in use for recovery and win7 startup) and 2 dynamic!

Comment: It is not clear your question again or I can't understand you. Please use this command: `sudo fdisk -l` and update your question.

Comment: 2 hidden primary part. inaccesible- unchangeable as OEM and win7 startup (100mb) in use.
2 part as dynamic. incl 1 part as win7 OS part. Both impossible to change in primary again. ( See this link – grahammechanical  )
I can´t delete all part as suggested since 2 are inaccessible! And on 1 dyn. part. is the win7 OS!
Fortunately win7 is still able to work, thnx to the hidden part of 100mb incl the start up part.
Impossible to install Ubuntu since it needs an primary part.

Hope this clears out my problem. Question is how to make the dyn parts primary again in this situation?

Comment: Unless you don't update your question with the nedded output, we only help you with guessing something. First, Ubuntu does not need to install within a primary partition, it just needs **a** partition. Second, if you have dynamic partitions, revert them to basic (or what is its name) one. And shape your partitions.

Comment: i want to install Ub in  its own part. Trying to do so i got the message 'not poss to install on a dynamic part'...

Comment: @J.S. Beethoven, primary partition is not the only "own" partition. You can install Ubuntu anywhere on the disk. Please, please put the output to your question. And please, refer my previous answer. If your disk is a dynamic one, just revert it to basic one. You can find more and more info around Google about that.

Answer (score 0):

On my new laptop are 2 hidden primary part. inaccesible- unchangeable as OEM and win7 startup (100mb) in use.
2 part as dynamic. incl 1 part as win7 OS part. Both impossible to change back in primary again. ( as explained in grahammechanical link above )
I can´t delete all part as suggested since 2 are inaccessible! And on 1 dyn. part. is the win7 OS!

Fortunately win7 is still able to work, thnx to the hidden part of 100mb which includes the start up part.
Its impossible to install Ubuntu since it needs an primary part., that i don´t know how to make in this very situation.

Hope this clears out my problem. Question is how to make the dyn parts primary again in this situation?

Comment: You don't need to add an answer to your own question. If you have more info, just update your question please.

Comment: situation shown during Ubuntu instaal: Sda1 = 1mb- Sda2 = 13.7GB- Sda3 = 105MB - Sda4 = 92GB- FREE SPACE 214 GB. BUT  unusable  NO ROOT FILESYSTEM IS DEFINED        ???